# Identifying unique index numbers from a list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list `A` containing an array with indices. I want to print all the unique index numbers by scanning each `[i,j]`. In `[0,3]`, `i=0,j=3`. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
A=[np.array([[[0, 1],
        [0, 3],
        [1, 3],
        [3, 4],
        [3, 6],
        [4, 5],
        [4, 7],
        [5, 7],
        [6, 4]]])]
```

The expected output is

```
A=[0,1,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Comment: `set(A[0].flatten())` or `np.unique(A[0])`

Answer (score 0):

[numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) has this very cool function `np.unique`.

Simply to get the output `A=[0,1,3,4,5,6,7]`

`B = np.unique(A[0])`

Output :
`[0 1 3 4 5 6 7]`

Answer (score 0):

```
A=[[0, 1],[0, 3],[1, 3],[3, 4],[3, 6],[4, 5],[4, 7],[5, 7],[6, 4]]
K = []
for _ in range(len(A)):
    K.extend(A[_])
print(set(K))
```

OUTPUT:

```
{0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Comment: Your A and OP's A don't match.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

`A` is basically a list and within list you make an array.
**Do this:**

```
def unique(A):
    x = np.array(A)
    print(np.unique(x))
unique(A)
```

if `A` is an array we can simply **do this:**

```
np.unique(A)
```